# Oracle : Cannot query a view of another schema that also has linked tables to another schema

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a view created under a user "**dbaUserA**". View query uses a table from another user "**dbaUserB**". Both users are dba.

view name: **v_valid_trx**
with query of

```
 Select trx_no,trx_date,order_item 
 from trx_table a left outer join  dbaUserB.cancelled_trx b on a.trx_no=b.trx_no
 where b.trx_no is null;
```

I have created a less privilege user "**userC**" but with select privilege on

```
dbaUserA.trx_table
dbaUserB.cancelled_trx.
dbaUserA.v_valid_trx
```

I can select directly trx_table and cancelled_trx from those different schemas however i cannot select on the view **v_valid_trx**.

Oracle prompts

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>   01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
>              without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
>              attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
>              system privileges.
>              When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
>              if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
>              than the current login.
>   *Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
>              the required privileges.
>              For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
>              the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
>              administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label. Error at Line: 1 Column: 21

Been wrestling with these for hours now. I can't seem to understand the cause of the error when i can freely select the base tables.

please help :)

Comment: I'd guess dbaUserB needs to `grant select on cancelled_trx to dbausera with grant option`, though that's a bit of a guess without a complete test case. dbaUserB gave dbaUserA permission to query it, not to share it with anyone else.

Comment: Also note your command-line access to the base tables may be via a role (such as DBA) which won't be any use for base tables within views.

Comment: when i did the grants for the view i was on console as sysdba all the time. I re-granted the select on the base table to dbauserA now with grant option. Thanks a lot William for the correct guess. :) Did not know that oracle privileges works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user A grants permissions on a table to user B, that doesn't give B permission to expose that data to anyone else, even via a view. The extended grant syntax `WITH GRANT OPTION` must be used to allow this.

For example, say USER_A creates a table and grants SELECT on it to USER_B. (To make it clear who is running each command I've made their SQL> prompts reflect their username.)

```
USER_A> create table cancelled_trx(dummy varchar2(1));

USER_A> grant select on cancelled_trx to USER_B;
```

That doesn't give USER_B permission to pass the grant on to USER_C:

```
USER_B> grant select on USER_A.cancelled_trx to USER_C;
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

The error message is more specific for views:

```
USER_B> create or replace view test_view as select * from USER_A.cancelled_trx;

View created.

USER_B> grant select on test_view to USER_C
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for 'USER_A.CANCELLED_TRX'
```

To allow this, the owner (USER_A) would have to

```
USER_A> grant select on cancelled_trx to USER_B with grant option;
```

The other point raised by your question is scope of roles. Grants made to roles don't apply within views or definer-rights procedures. Therefore if USER_A granted select on cancelled_trx to ROLE_X, and USER_B had ROLE_X, USER_B could query cancelled_trx but not use it in a view or a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You might first what to confirm that userC indeed has select permissions on the view dbaUserB.v_valid_trx.

I believe permissions are stored in SYSTABLEPERMS.

I know of at least one other RDBMS which never errors when applying permissions, even if the grant statement is meaningless.

Also, I'm not convinced you need to grant select permissions to userC for the base tables, isn't that the purpose of a view?

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: This is Oracle, so it's the `DBA|ALL|USER_TAB_PRIVS%` views, and userC does need to grant permissions.